# Type safety warning when parameter is parameterized descendant of parametrized class

Tags: java, generics

I have a method with signature:

```
public static <T, E extends PxViewFull<T> > E create(Class<T> dtoClass, Class<E> viewClass)
```

When I call it for parametrized second parameter I get Type safety warning. Call of the method:

```
private PxViewFull<Output40942DTO> output40813 = PxViewFull.create(Output40813DTO.class, ServiceOutputView.class);
```

ServiceOutputView signature:

```
public class ServiceOutputView<T extends ServiceCall<?>> extends PxViewFull<T>
```

How can I get infer generic type arguments to get rid of the warning?

Comment: Note that `ServiceOutputView.class` merely points to `Class<ServiceOutputView>`, where `ServiceOutputView` is a raw type.

Comment: Can you produce a minimalistic running code example? Where your problem is reproduced?

Comment: @mike All you need is in the post already: just create empty classes/method with described signatures and try to create field as described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Paul Bellora answered your question.

ServiceOutputView.class is of type Class[ServiceOutputView[?]] and your parameter at the call site expects Class[ServiceOutputView[Output40942DTO]], so you get an unchecked method invocation exception when you try and pass Class[ServiceView[?] into Class[ServiceOutputView[Output40942DTO]] which is what your method type parameters tell it to expect.

UPDATE:
Here's an arrangement that will not issue a warning:

```
public class Parameter {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

        PxViewFull<OutputDTO> output40813 = PxViewFull.create(OutputDTO.class, ServiceOutputView.class);
    }

}

class ServiceCall<X> {

}

class OutputDTO extends ServiceCall<OutputDTO> {

    public OutputDTO serviceCall() {

        // i guess i pupulate myself?
        return this;
    }
}

class PxViewFull<X> {

    private X dtoObject;
    private Class<X> dtoObjectType;

    public static <P1, P2 extends PxViewFull<?>, RESULT extends PxViewFull<P1>> RESULT create(
            Class<P1> dtoClass,
            Class<P2> viewClass) throws Exception {

        return null;
    }

    public void setDtoObjectType(final Class<X> dtoObjectType) {

        this.dtoObjectType = dtoObjectType;
    }

    public void setModel(Object o) {

        if (!dtoObjectType.isInstance(o))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        this.dtoObject = dtoObjectType.cast(o);
    }

}

class ServiceOutputView<T extends ServiceCall<?>> extends PxViewFull<T> {

}
```

the create method will have to contain an unchecked cast though, and the best thing to do is just slap an @SuppressWarning on it and make sure the reason is clearly stated in the javadoc for the method.

Comment: I understand, but the question is: Does it exist a way to declare all in such way to not get Type safety warning? Usually it is possible to parameterize classes/methods or use ? to not get the warning. But I haven't find any way to do this in this case.

Comment: With the structure you're using, you'll have to do something "unsafe" eventually regardless because there is just not enough type information carried across the layers with this design.  Java Generics != Templates and are not reified.